# How to use confusion matrix to evaluate accuracy of a topic model (LDA)?

Tags: topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

Here's my understanding of topic model, suppose there are 4 topics generated from running LDA from the cleaned corpus(user reviews).

<Topic *j*: word1(prob.), word2(prob.), word3(prob.)>

**Generated Topics**

> Topic 1: word1(0.4), word2(0.4), word3(0.2)

> Topic 2: word1(0.7), word2(0.2), word3(0.1)

> Topic 3: word1(0.6), word2(0.3), word3(0.1)

> Topic 4: word1(0.4), word2(0.3), word3(0.3)

How do we use confusion matrix to evaluate the topic model?